# BeagleBone Black - Bonescript Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, debian, beagleboneblack

I am having issues running scripts using Bonescript on my BeagleBone black. When I run the scripts in a web browser, it executes as normal. However, when I try executing them from a terminal window, they won't run.

```
#!/bin/bash
var b = require('bonescript');

var leds = ["USR0", "USR1", "USR2", "USR3", "P9_14"];

for(var i in leds) {
    b.pinMode(leds[i], b.OUTPUT);
}

var state = b.LOW;
for(var i in leds) {
    b.digitalWrite(leds[i], state);
}

setInterval(toggle, 1000);

function toggle() {
    state = (state == b.LOW) ? b.HIGH : b.LOW;
    for(var i in leds) {
        b.digitalWrite(leds[i], state);
    }
}




debian@beaglebone:~$ ./BlinkLED.js 
./BlinkLED.js: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./BlinkLED.js: line 2: `var b = require('bonescript');'
```

Comment: I just tried on my BBB your code from console, typing:" node BlinkLED.js" 
Everything works ok

Comment: node BlinkLED.js results in

Error: Cannot find module 'bonescript'